# Adapt flex div's width to content but flex items in separate lines

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="flex_item1">Item</div>
  <label for="" class="flex_item1">I am a Label</label>

  <!-- This whole block needs to be in a new line -->
  <div class="flex_item2">Item 2</div>
  <label for="" class="flex_item2">I am a Label 2</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex_container{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.flex_item1{
  background-color: red;
}

.flex_item2{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f6atroh2/9/

I want the flex_container div's width to adapt to the flex_item's content. I've seen people use `display: inline-flex` but that keeps the inner divs from being in separate lines, which is something I want.

Comment: Can you share css ?

Comment: @AkshayAggarwal updated original post. also fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f6atroh2/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your html to this.

```
 <div class="flex_container">
   <div class="temp">
      <div class="flex_item1">Item</div>
      <label for="" class="flex_item1">I am a Label</label>
 </div>
  <!-- This whole block needs to be in a new line -->
<div class="temp">
   <div class="flex_item2">Item 2</div>
   <label for="" class="flex_item2">I am a Label 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And update css to this.

```
.flex_container{

    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.flex_item1{
  background-color: red;
 }

.flex_item2{
   background-color: yellow;
 }

.temp{

  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
 }
```

Comment: how you want your divs to align? , I thought you want in seperate lines

Comment: the whole red block should be in one line, followed by the whole yellow block in another line.

Comment: I have updated my answer , see if it is what you are looking for.